# Codecademy- A Day at the Supper Market: Stocking Out

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
shopping_list = ["banana", "orange", "apple"]

stock = {
    "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}

prices = {
    "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
}

# Write your code below!
def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0
    for hi in food:
        if stock[hi] > 0:
            total = total + prices[hi]
            stock[i] = stock[i] - 1

    return total
```

The Codecademy interpreter returns with this statement "calling compute_bill with a list containing 2 pears, 1 orange and 8 bananas resulted in 39.5 instead of the correct 31.5".
I don't understand what is wrong with the script that makes it run incorrectly.
If able could you also explain how compute_bill(food) is able to connect itself with the shopping_list, stock and prices?

Comment: Actually it should result in `39.5`. The calculation is correct.

Comment: Is there a problem with this line stock[i] = stock[i] . i is not defined

Comment: References to the value at `stock[i]` need to be changed to `stock[hi]`

Comment: It should result in 39.5 only if there are 8 bananas in stock. if your list only has 6 bananas, it should result in 31.5

Comment: The code you've shown us should raise `NameError: global name 'i' is not defined` on the `stock[i] = stock[i] - 1` line. Was that a typo?

Comment: Problem was solved thanks for the heads up @tdelaney, I changed [i] to [hi].

Answer (score -1):

This code is right:

```
shopping_list = ["banana", "orange", "apple"]

stock = {
    "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}

prices = {
    "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
}

# Write your code below!
def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0
    for key in food:
        if (stock[key] > 0):
            total += prices[key]
            stock[key] = stock[key] - 1

    return total

print compute_bill(shopping_list)  
stock = {
    "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}
```

Comment: Explain how this answers the question